# How do i prevent bootstrap typeahead from double filtering non-matching results from ajax call

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using bootstrap typeahead with a jQuery ajax which we will call FILTER#1.  In my case, an ajax search like "great tank" or "greattank" both produce a "Great Tank" ajax result but typeahead is 2nd guessing my results and double filtering out (we will call FILTER#2) the second result because of the space.  It is also possible that my ajax result back may be totally different than what was typed.  I need typeahead to trust that the results provided were valid and display them regardless of an exact lowercase text match.

I'd like to have the following behavior:

1. If there is a matching word in the results highlight it
2. If there is a non-matching word display it unhighlighted but leave it in the result list vs. filtering it out.

(1) works OOTB, but (2) is the missing feature I'm looking for.  If I can't have (1) and (2) I'd be ok with dropping (1).

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/PE9mN/

```
        $("#title2").typeahead({
        source: function( request, response ) {
              var mockResults2 = ["Great Tank War", 
                                  "Great Train Robbery",
                                  "other random result my server produced"];
            response(mockResults2); 
            // I expect this to display both items regardless of $("#title2").val() 
            // In my case, the server was smart enough to realize that 
            // "greattank" may match "great tank"
            // and it even added a 3rd value that I want to display.
            }
           });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add the following option to typeahead:

```
  matcher: function(item) {
      return true;
  }
```

Then no "second" filtering will apply.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this at initialization as below

```
  //Typeahead autocomplete for address
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        ajax: {
           .....
        },
        matcher: function () { return true; }
    });
```